# Авторизация с использованием HttpClient C# на сервере со всплывающим окном

Tags: c#, .net, http

Хочу сделать программу для получения прогноза погоды (использую API meteomatics), но при отправке запроса на сервер просит авторизацию [image: простая авторизация, логин и пароль]

только начал изучать эту сферу и не знаю как решите эту проблему, буду рад помощи

Пытался найти решение, но авторизацию нашел только на отдельной странице, а не в таком вот всплывающем окне

```cs
        static async Task<Weather> GetDate()
        {
            const string API = @"https://api.meteomatics.com/2023-10-19T00:00:00Z--2023-10-22T00:00:00Z:PT1H/t_2m:C/46.390890,30.724842/json";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            var data = await client.GetAsync(API);
            string content = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(content);

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(content);
        }
```

Comment: `https://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@api.meteomatics.com/2023-10-19T00:00:00Z--2023-10-22T00:00:00Z:PT1H/t_2m:C/46.390890,30.724842/json` ?

Comment: Не создавайте клиент на каждый запрос, создайте один на все запросы `private static readonly HttpClient client = new();`